# How can I count number of occurrences of unique row in MATLAB ?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like following,

```
A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
     4     5     6
     1     2     3
```

I could extract unique rows in this matrix using command `A_unique = unique(A,'rows')` and result as follows

```
A_unique =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

I need to find number of times each rows exists in the main matrix `A`
Some thing like following

```
A_unique_count =

     2
     3
     2
     1
```

How can I find count of unique rows? Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance

Manu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) gives you the index of the unique row in the original array. You can use this with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to count the number of occurrences.

For example:

```
A = [1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
     4     5     6
     1     2     3];

[uniquerow, ~, rowidx] = unique(A, 'rows'); 
noccurrences = accumarray(rowidx, 1)
```

Returns:

```
noccurrences =

     2
     3
     2
     1
```

As expected

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [@excaza's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46781768/2586922). But just for variety:

```
A_unique_count = diff([0; find([any(diff(sortrows(A), [], 1), 2); 1])]);
```